# html tables alignment using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my alignment for tables and a map on an html page. 
It looks like this at the moment:
[image]

1,2,3 are all tables, using CSS:

```
table {float:left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 20%; margin: 10px
}
```

and 4 is a googlemap using:

```
#location{width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

I would like 3 to go beneath 2, with 4 always on the right:

[image]

Comment: Use flex-box with column direction and wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap the two tables into a single div, then float that div.

```css
.float-left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.full-width caption {
  margin: 12px 0 2px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.google-map {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="float-left">
  <table class="full-width">
    <caption>Table 1</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="float-left">
  <table class="full-width">
    <caption>Table 2</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="full-width">
    <caption>Table 3</caption>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="google-map">
  Google Map Here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put 2 and 3 together in a parent container and make that `float: left`. If the widths of your elements are narrow enough to allow them to be placed in three columns as shown in your question, this should be enough.